# Seam swallowing JDBC exceptions

Tags: java, seam

I'm working with Seam 2.1 but when I get a JDBC Exception throw proxy call, the framework swallows the exception without logging it. There is any way to show the exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/events.html#d0e5644)?

> JSF is surprisingly limited when it comes to exception handling. As a
>   partial workaround for this problem, Seam lets you define how a
>   particular class of exception is to be treated by annotating the
>   exception class, or declaring the exception class in an XML file. This
>   facility is meant to be combined with the EJB 3.0-standard
>   @ApplicationException annotation which specifies whether the exception
>   should cause a transaction rollback.